# How to get group of contacts list from Phone Contacts

Tags: java, android

```
btngal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_GROUP_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i,0);        
            }
        }); 

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (requestCode == 0) {
                Uri selectContact=data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn={Contacts.CONTENT_URI.toString()};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectContact,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
             filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

            }
        }

    }
```

While doing this action I am getting below error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/group }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to read contacts from native android app, you need permission, like this in your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Make sure you have that one.

Comment: Thanks Marko, now I am not getting above exception.