# Get contact phone number for a specific group

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get access to all mobile phone number of a specific group name "friends".

I guess I need to use :

```
Cursor dataCursor = getContentResolver().query(?????);
```

thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739807/how-to-get-group-of-contacts-list-from-phone-contacts

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403377/android-get-list-of-contacts-belonging-to-a-specific-group

Comment: thx but how to know the group ID ?